# Converting a 3D Array to a Dataframe

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, data-manipulation

I have a 3D array of dimensions 48 x 165 x 27 (48 source ROIs, 165 target ROIs, and 27 participants), in a CSV file. Each page is a new participant.

I would like to convert this into a dataframe in which each participant (27) has a row, and the column headers are all the possible combinations of the 48 source and 165 target ROIs (i.e. [Source #1 x Target #1],[Source #1 x Target #2],[Source #1 x Target #3]...).

How can I do this in R?

[image]

Comment: where is the data that has been read into R? use `dput` function to paste the data here

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: much more direct:

```r
data.frame(aperm(ary, c(3,1,2)))
#       src1.tgt1 src2.tgt1 src3.tgt1 src1.tgt2 src2.tgt2 src3.tgt2 src1.tgt3 src2.tgt3 src3.tgt3
# part1         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
# part2        10        11        12        13        14        15        16        17        18
# part3        19        20        21        22        23        24        25        26        27
# part4        28        29        30        31        32        33        34        35        36
```

The rest kept to show my over-engineered first attempt :-)

(Thanks @Onyambu!)

---

Using my sample data (below):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
apply(ary, 3, function(m) {
  as.data.frame.table(m) %>%
    transmute(Var = paste(Var1, Var2, sep = "_"), Freq) %>%
    spread(Var, Freq)
}) %>%
  bind_rows()
#   src1_tgt1 src1_tgt2 src1_tgt3 src2_tgt1 src2_tgt2 src2_tgt3 src3_tgt1 src3_tgt2 src3_tgt3
# 1         1         4         7         2         5         8         3         6         9
# 2        10        13        16        11        14        17        12        15        18
# 3        19        22        25        20        23        26        21        24        27
# 4        28        31        34        29        32        35        30        33        36
```

Walkthrough:

- we can convert a single plane of this 3d array into a 3-column table:

  ```r
  as.data.frame.table(ary[,,1]) %>% head
  #   Var1 Var2 Freq
  # 1 src1 tgt1    1
  # 2 src2 tgt1    2
  # 3 src3 tgt1    3
  # 4 src1 tgt2    4
  # 5 src2 tgt2    5
  # 6 src3 tgt2    6
  ```
- given this, we want to combine `Var1` and `Var2` into a single variable (to give the combinations), and then pivot from long to wide:

  ```r
  as.data.frame.table(ary[,,1]) %>%
    transmute(Var = paste(Var1, Var2, sep = "_"), Freq) %>%
    spread(Var, Freq)
  #   src1_tgt1 src1_tgt2 src1_tgt3 src2_tgt1 src2_tgt2 src2_tgt3 src3_tgt1 src3_tgt2 src3_tgt3
  # 1         1         4         7         2         5         8         3         6         9
  ```
- so we need to do this for each plane; given that this is an `array`, my first thought is

  ```r
  apply(ary, MARGIN=3, function(m) {...})
  ```

  where `MARGIN=` indicates which array to iterative over. For each call, `m` is a 3x3 matrix (in this example), one plane of the overall array.

This could probably be done simply in base R, but my luck with base R's reshaping is mixed; I find `tidyr::spread` straight-forward. Since I loaded that, I went ahead and used `dplyr` as well, though that part can easily be factored out as well.

---

Sample data:

```r
ary <- array(1:36, dim=c(3,3,4))
dimnames(ary) <- list(paste0("src", 1:3), paste0("tgt", 1:3), paste0("part", 1:4))
ary
# , , part1
#      tgt1 tgt2 tgt3
# src1    1    4    7
# src2    2    5    8
# src3    3    6    9
# , , part2
#      tgt1 tgt2 tgt3
# src1   10   13   16
# src2   11   14   17
# src3   12   15   18
# , , part3
#      tgt1 tgt2 tgt3
# src1   19   22   25
# src2   20   23   26
# src3   21   24   27
# , , part4
#      tgt1 tgt2 tgt3
# src1   28   31   34
# src2   29   32   35
# src3   30   33   36
```

Comment: what of  `data.frame(ary)`

Comment: `data.frame(ary)` does not combine the dimensions correctly for this problem, so I had to rearrange things. If you try it without `aperm`, you'll get columns such as `tgt1.part1` and row names of `src1`, etc. That's all.

Comment: Oops, good catch. I had needed `abind` some time ago for some multi-dim stuff and was only then using `aperm` on the same structures ... so I naturally tied the two together. Updated, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to specify row and column lengths so that R could populate the 27 parts?

Comment: I don't understand. I think your "27 parts" is referring to the participants, therefore the output *rows*, but the dimensions of the output here are defined by the input data and various combinations of `src` and `tgt` names.